# MySQL SQL Syntax error on GUI

Tags: java, mysql, connector

Hello I want to put 2 values to 2 columns in my table. I get those values from txtField and textField_1 (which are 2 textboxes on an GUI).

The problem is that whenever I push the button to register those values I get an syntax error on my mysql.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Registration (Username , Password ) VALUES (? ,?)";
                java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1,textField.getText());
                pst.setString(2,textField_1.getText());
                int rs = pst.executeUpdate(query);
```

If I put static values instead of ?, is working.

Comment: It is the standard , "You got an MySQL error in your syntax, check for..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use prepared statement for select query in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692296/how-to-use-prepared-statement-for-select-query-in-java)

Comment: `query` parameter not needed. http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Registration (Username , Password ) VALUES (? ,?)";
                java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1,textField.getText());
                pst.setString(2,textField_1.getText());
                int rs = pst.executeUpdate();
```

use [executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

Comment: This was it, I'll put it as an answer soon.