# How to check if email is already registered in MYSQL db using SpringMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

How to check if email is already registered in MYSQL db using SpringMVC?

i also try

```
public boolean exists(String email) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Spring3", "root", "root");

    Statement st=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Registration");
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Registration");
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (email.equals(rs.getString("email"))) {
            System.out.println("Email already registerd!!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use prepared statement for select query in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692296/how-to-use-prepared-statement-for-select-query-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Registration where email='"+email+"'");
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("Exists!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Does Not Exist!");
    }
...
```