# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password = ?' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having a problem with SQL. this is my code and I don't know why and don't know to fix it. I use Java EE and Eclipse to do this.

```
public void userLogin(String username,String password) {

   Connection conn = null;  
   PreparedStatement ps = null; 
   ResultSet rs = null;

   try {        
      conn = JDBCUtilsWithProperties.getConnection();
      String sql = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?;";
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1,   username);
      ps.setString(2,   password);
      rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

      if(rs.next()) {   
         System.out.println("SUCESS");
      } else {
         System.out.println("FAIL");
      }

      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         JDBCUtilsWithProperties.release(rs, ps, conn);
      }     
   }
}

public class JDBCUtilsWithProperties {

   private static String driverClass;
   private static String url;
   private static String username;
   private static String password;

   private JDBCUtilsWithProperties(){}

   static {
      try {
         readConfig();
         Class.forName(driverClass);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void readConfig() {    
      Properties pp = new Properties();
      try { 
         pp.load(new FileInputStream("src//config.properties"));
         driverClass = pp.getProperty("driverClass");
         url = pp.getProperty("url");
         username = pp.getProperty("username");
         password = pp.getProperty("password");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
      }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
       try {
          return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
    }

    public static Statement createStatement() {
       Connection conn = getConnection();
       Statement stat = null;
       try {
          stat = conn.createStatement();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return  stat;
    }

    public static void release(ResultSet rs,Statement stat,Connection conn){
       if(rs != null) {
          try {
             rs.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO: handle exception
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          rs = null;
        }
        if(stat != null) {
           try {
              stat.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
           stat = null;
        }
        if(conn != null) {
           try {
              conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
           conn = null;
        }
    }

    public static void release(Statement stat,Connection conn) {
       if(stat != null){
          try {
             stat.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          stat = null;
        }
        if(conn != null) {
           try {
              conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
           conn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When run it appears a notification:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '? AND password=?' at line 1"

Comment: I don't think you need a **";"** in your sql statement !

Comment: Also, [MySQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to execute PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680503/preparedstatement-does-not-work-with-mysql-jdbc)

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta `;` it's don't matter. You can put `;` end of the query

Answer (score 7):

if you use prepared Statement, execute function does not have the SQL query as Parameter:

```
String sql = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?;";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, password);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    ^^
```

Also see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) of `Statement` class

> boolean execute(String sql)
>                   throws SQLException
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results.
>   In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return
>   multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore
>   this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may
>   return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an
>   unknown SQL string.  The execute method executes an SQL statement and
>   indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods
>   getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and
>   getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).
>
> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or
>   CallableStatement.